# How to always returned cached object with Spring's cache abstraction

Tags: spring, caching

Is there a way using the Spring Framework's cache abstraction to *always* return a cached incarnation of an object?

I have an image resizing method. The `resize()` method returns a temporary `File` which is cached using my  hand-rolled binary `Cache` using Spring's cache abstraction. The method itself is cached via `@Cacheable` and all works fine.

The difficulty is that I need to somehow clean up the temporary files generated by this method after they've been added to the cache.

In other words, the current behaviour is:

1. First invocation of `resize()` - returns generated file at `/tmp/somefile.jpg` which is added to the cache by Spring.
2. Second invocation of `resize()` - results in a cache hit, so returns file from `/myCache/somefile.jpg`

This results in temporary files lingering around.

I can't delete the source file in my `Cache#put(Object key, Object value)` method, as this is the file that's returned from the non-cached invocation of the associated method.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation and solved it with an elegant solution? Ideally, I'd like all invocations of the cacheable method to return the cached object.

Comment: I hope the only solution isn't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827267/how-to-prevent-a-return-value-from-cache-to-be-changed-in-spring-cacheable?rq=1, as my AspectJ is decidedly ropey...!

Answer (score 2):

I've worked around the issue by interacting directly with `Cache#get()` and `Cache#put()`, bypassing Spring's more elegant annotation-based approach.

It's not beautiful, but it works.