# how to merge properties from one Java object to another in Java using Spring [SpEL]?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I'm using Spring but not that familiar with all its capabilities. Looking for a good way to copy fields from one Java object instance to another. I've seen [How to copy properties from one Java bean to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835416/how-to-copy-properties-from-one-java-bean-to-another) but what i'm looking for is more specific, so here are the details:

Suppose I have two instances of some class P, source & target, which have getters and setters a,b,c,d and 20 others.
I want to copy the properties of of source into target, but only for all properties in a list of property names. It does not matter what is the value of any property in either source or target.
In other words, if the list is {"a", "b"}
then i just want the following to happen:

```
P source;
P target;
List<string> properties; 

//source, target are populated. properties is {"a", "b"}  
//Now I need some Spring (SpEL?) trick to do the equivalent of:
target.setA(source.getA());
target.setB(source.getB());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079458/copy-specific-fields-by-using-beanutils-copyproperties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using Java Reflection:

```
Field[] fields = source.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

for (Field f: fields) {
    if (properties.contains(f.getName())) {

        f.setAccessible(true);

        f.set(destination, f.get(source));
    }
}
```

Here are some tutorials on Reflection:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html

Be careful though, [Reflection has specific use cases](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/193526/is-it-a-bad-habit-to-overuse-reflection).

---

### Using Spring BeanWrapper:

```
BeanWrapper srcWrap = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(source);
BeanWrapper destWrap = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(destination);

properties.forEach(p -> destWrap.setPropertyValue(p, srcWrap.getPropertyValue(p)));
```

Credit for Spring BeanWrapper example goes to:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5079864/6510058

Comment: Thanks Leonz, for the very comprehensive answer. Since I'm using Spring, I used your BeanWrapper solution. I had to make a trivial change to the last line since I'm restricted to Java 7 at the moment. Not bothring posting it. Perhaps you should...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think SpEL requires here, it can be solved with [BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object, Object, String...)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...-). According your example, if your class has properties 'a','b','c' and you want to copy only first two, you can call it like so

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target, "c");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well, is there an easy way in Spring to get a List of all the properties of a class? because I will need that list and I will need to remove from it all the properties in my list before i can call copyProperties

Comment: @inor, sure, you just need a little bit of dark magic of reflection `List<String> fieldNames = Arrays.asList(P.class.getDeclaredFields()).stream().map(Field::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Hi Sergey. Thanks for the great answer. I learned from it that i need to catch up on dark magic. I up-ticked your answer but I'm going to give @leonz the check mark as his answer seems more efficient as it does not require traversal of all the fields

Comment: @inor, it's ok! I'm glad that community helped you to solve this.